# absolute value random walk also a markov chain

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, random-walk

Consider the random walk $S_{n}$ for $n \geq 1$. Specifically, let $X_{1},X_{2},..$ be Independent with

$$
\mathbb{P}(X_{n}=1) = p,~~\mathbb{P}(X_{n}=-1) = 1- p =:q
$$
and $S_{n} = \sum_{k=1}^{n}X_{k}$. I have read in the book of Ross, Stochastic Processes on page 166, that $|S_{n}|$ is also a markov chain. He uses Proposition 4.1.1. to prove this. Here the Proposition
[image]

My question is why 
$$
\mathbb{P}(S_{n} = i,...,|S_{j+1}| = i_{j+1},|S_{j}| = 0) = p^{\frac{n-j}{2}+\frac{i}{2}}q^{\frac{n-j}{2}-\frac{i}{2}}
$$
and
$$
\mathbb{P}(S_{n} = -i,...,|S_{j+1}| = i_{j+1},|S_{j}| = 0) = p^{\frac{n-j}{2}-\frac{i}{2}}q^{\frac{n-j}{2}+\frac{i}{2}}
$$

I know that if $S_{n} = i$ then because of the definition of $j$ $S_{j} = 0$ and $S_{j+1},...,S_{n-1} > 0$ and similar for $S_{n} = -i$ I have $S_{j+1},...,S_{n-1} < 0$. 
I hope someone can help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The probabilities in your last two displayed equations aren't quite right. It's not

$$
\mathbb P(S_n=\pm i,\ldots,|S_{j+1}|=i_{j+1},|S_j|=0)=p^{\frac{n-j}2\pm\frac i2}q^{\frac{n-j}2\mp\frac i2}
$$

but

$$
\mathbb P(S_n=\pm i,\ldots,|S_{j+1}|=i_{j+1}\;\big|\;|S_j|=0)=p^{\frac{n-j}2\pm\frac i2}q^{\frac{n-j}2\mp\frac i2}\;,
$$

that is, given that we know that $S_j=0$, the probability for the remaining sequence to occur is given by the right-hand side. This is the case because to reach $\pm i$ in $n-j$ steps, we need to take $\frac{n-j}2\pm\frac i2$ steps in the positive direction with probability $p$ and $\frac{n-j}2\mp\frac i2$ steps in the negative direction with probability $q$: The total number of steps is $\frac{n-j}2\pm\frac i2+\frac{n-j}2\mp\frac i2=n-j$, and the distance traveled is $\frac{n-j}2\pm\frac i2-\left(\frac{n-j}2\mp\frac i2\right)=\pm i$.

Comment: Could the downvoter please explain?

Comment: I don't understand your answer. Can you please be more specific?

Comment: $$
\mathbb{P}(|S_{n}| = i,,...,|S_{1}| = i_{1}) = 
\mathbb{P}(S_{n} = -i,...,|S_{1}| = i_{1}) + 
\mathbb{P}(S_{n} = i,...,|S_{i}| = i_{i})$$. Your answer make no sense. So please read the question carefully

Comment: @gregor: You were right, I hadn't read the question carefully enough. I corrected the answer. (I would also have done it if you'd been slightly more friendly :-)

Comment: I don't meant it badly (: Thanks for your answer

Comment: hi Joriki, why don't you put a binomial coefficient in it ? for me it's lacking that coefficient in order to take account of every possibilities. Is it because the path is already indicated?

Comment: @MarineGalantin: Yes, this is the probability for a specific path to occur, specified by the $i_k$. The binomial coefficient occurs in the probability

$$\mathbb P(S_n=\pm i\;\big|\;|S_j|=0)=\binom{n-j}{\frac{n-j}2\pm\frac i2}p^{\frac{n-j}2\pm\frac i2}q^{\frac{n-j}2\mp\frac i2}\;,$$

for *any* path from $0$ to $\pm i$ to occur in $n-j$ steps.